# UNUserNotification doesn't fire out my local notification under iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

In code I try to do it like this:

```
import UserNotifications

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { _, _ in }
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Hello Staff"
        content.body = "Customer just ordered a milk with croissant"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let date = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10))
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "abcde", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)
}
```

All happens within `AppDelegate`. But I can't see any local notification. Why?

Comment: it is working in all other device?

Comment: I dont know;) I try to implement it first time...;) I works nowhere;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. I guess the problem is that your app is active when you receive the notifications. `iOS` shows system notifications only if the app is not active. If app is active when notifications fires, the system triggers the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` method so you could handle the notification by yourself.

So since you set a notification time with a delay for `10` seconds, you need to run your app, then close it and wait for `10` seconds. Notification should appear if you give your app such a permission.

Comment: It is an awesome answer;) Works... but can I present notification when app is in foreground mode?;)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Sure. That's what `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` needs for. Create your own delegate and system will notify you when notifications fire. Then you can make any UI changes you want.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk If you meant the showing the system notification when the app is running, the answer is **no**, you need to use delegate and show custom notifications.